# Is there a way to share LinkedIn post to Instagram story?

Tags: linkedin, sharing, instagram

Just the title says, is there a way to share a LinkedIn post to an Instagram story without coding, hitting APIs, but by using the default Instagram UI/UX (or third-party apps)?